# Loading images with Glide from dynamic URL

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I use Glide library in my Android project to update avatar from URL that comes in response from API.
**The problem is that when I try to load different image (from different URL) to the same `imageView` it shows me an image that was downloaded first time.** (URL forming works fine, I tried it in browser and it shows the needed image)

Here is my code:
**EditProfileFragment.xml**

```
public static final String IMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://myapi.com/img/";

String imageUrl = Const.IMAGE_BASE_URL + cb_getProfile.photo;  //imageName.jpg

                    Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(imageUrl)
                            .animate(R.anim.abc_fade_in)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(mImageView_photo);
```

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this problem by adding a `StringSignature` when loading image from the URL.
[Source](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation)

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .animate(R.anim.abc_fade_in)
    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
    .centerCrop()
    .into(mImageView_photo)
;
```

Thanks to Yoav Sternberg.

Comment: If you only want to invalidate every 10 minutes you can also divide: `currentTimeMillies() / (10 * 60 * 1000)`.